# How to add container to list in sencha touch 2?

Tags: javascript, list, sencha-touch-2, containers

Is there any way to add instance of `Ext.Container` to the `Ext.List` instead of making `ListItem` or just plain text?

Answer (score 0):

Considering myContainer as an Ext.Container instance and myList as an Ext.List instance, you could just do:

```
myList.add(myContainer);
```